# Separate 1 tables into two based on conditions and then JOIN the two tables keeping NULL instead of duplicating

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a "Customer History" table which holds different type of entries.

I want to get entries with Type = 'E-mail' and Source = 'External' or Source = 'Customer'.

So I would get:

| Id | Type | Source | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | E-mail | External | 12/02/24 |
| 11 | E-mail | External | 13/02/24 |
| 11 | E-mail | Customer | 10/02/24 |

MY MAIN GOAL is to then modify this result to get:

| Id | External source Date | Customer Source Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 12/02/24 | 10/02/24 |
| 11 | 13/02/24 | NULL |

I just need to have to date columns, one to be taking dates only from 'E-mail' entries with Source - 'External', and one taking dates when source - 'Customer'

I have tried all different JOINs, I have applied WHERE conditions, adding conditions to the ON clause in the JOIN itself, read different posts in here and in Google, and I can't make it work.

Comment: Why are you combining the first and third row, instead of the second and third?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using window function `row_number()` to assign a unique identifier to each row according to its source, then apply the conditional aggregation using the aggregate function `MAX()`  :

```
select Id,
       max(case when Source = 'External' then Date end) as 'External source Date',
       max(case when Source = 'Customer' then Date end) as 'Customer source Date'
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by Id, Type, Source order by Date) as rn
  from mytable
) as s
group by Id, Type, rn;
```

Results :

```
Id  External source Date    Customer source Date
11  2024-02-12              2024-02-10
11  2024-02-13              null
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/lJR6v0sz)